# Работа с несколькими формами в Visual C++ 2010

Tags: visual-c++

Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста,как в Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 из главной формы приложения поменять свойство элемента на другой форме. Т.е. в приложении имеется 2 формы. На первой имеются label и кнопка открывающая вторую форму. На второй форме находятся находятся textbox, label и кнопка. По нажатию на кнопку в первой форме нужно открыть вторую форму (это получилось), записать в label какой-то текст. Когда на второй форме нажмут на кнопку нужно значение текстового поля поместить в label на первой форме!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы поменять свойства никаких трудностей нет, главное передать в дочернию (вторую) форму, ее родительску (к примеру по клику кнопки в первой форме), а имея эту форму, из дочерней можно легко поменять значение нужно элемента (в вашем случае label'ы)
P.S. Если обьяснил не  понятно - милости просим в комент)

Comment: Не понятно, можно подробнее?

Comment: прошу прощения только сейчас заметил что C++, а не C#, но думаю особых проблем возникнуть не должно, в случае с ++ надо сделать ссылку (*) на класс первой формы, при создание второй формы надо эту ссылку чему то прировнять (первой форме естественно), а затем когда надо обращаться к первой форме через ссылку (что типо `form1->label1.Text="ad"`)
Вообщем идея вот она

Comment: спасибо попробую

Comment: P.S. офтоп, после получения ответа на вопрос, необходимо отметить лучший (для вас) ответ галочкой (возле голосования слева)

Comment: уже отметил, еще раз спасибо